# Fazer um UPDATE com o valor de outro Banco de dados

Tags: c#, sql

Meu banco esta assim:

```
cd_endereco  | ds_endereco
1            | Rua joão e maria
2            | Rua Manuel Silva
```

E no outro banco de Dados, tenho as mesmas colunas, entretendo tenho `cd_cliente`.
Quero passar os valores desse tabela para a do cliente.

Meu código esta assim:

```
"UPDATE tb_cliente SET ds_endereco=(
SELECT ds_endereco FROM tb_enderecos WHERE cd_endereco='"+codigoEndereco+"'
) WHERE cd_cliente=30"
```

<sub>OBS: As quebras de linha não existem, é apenas para facilitar a leitura aqui no site</sub>

Comment: Acho que não entendi bem sua questão ainda. Por favor dê a estrutura dos dois bancos de dados. Você quer manter os mesmos cd_cliente dos dois lados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a sua versão do SQL Server for superior ao 2008, você possuí acesso à cláusula `MERGE`.

Quando você quer manter informações sincronizadas entre duas tabelas (e 2 bancos de dados), ela é excelente. Com ela, você seta uma **origem** e **destino**, e instruí o que o banco deve fazer para cada linha que existir na **origem**. Exemplo:

- Se existir na origem e destino, atualiza o destino
- Se não existir no destino, insere o registro
- Se não existir na origem, remove da tabela destino (provavelmente o registro foi removido na origem).

Exemplo de como ficaria:

```
 MERGE bancoDadosCliente..tb_cliente as target
 USING (SELECT cd_cliente, ds_endereco FROM bancoDadosOrigem..tb_cliente) AS source
 ON (target.cd_cliente = source.cd_cliente)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET ds_endereco = source.ds_endereco
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    THEN DELETE
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    INSERT (cd_cliente, ds_endereco)
    VALUES (source.cd_cliente, source.ds_endereco)
```

Veja referências: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

**EDIÇÃO**

Se você quer comandos mais simples, você pode usar simples `INSERT`s e `UPDATE`s, mas vai ter que fazer um controle mais estrito na não. Exemplos:

Para atualizar registros que no outro banco que já possuam um `cd_cliente` cadastrado

```
UPDATE d
SET
  d = ds_endereco -- aqui voce coloca uma lista das colunas a atualizar
FROM dbDestino..cd_cliente d
INNER JOIN dbOrigem..cd_cliente c
WHERE d.cd_cliente = c.cd_cliente
```

Para inserir os registro que não existem no destino:

```
INERT INTO dbDestino..cd_cliente (cd_cliente, ds_endereco)
SELECT c.cd_cliente, c.ds_endereco
FROM dbDestino..cd_cliente d
OUTER JOIN dbOrigem..cd_cliente c ON d.cd_cliente = c.cd_cliente
WHERE d.cd_cliente IS NULL -- pega registros que não existem no destino e insere
```

Apaga os registro que não deveriam existir (foram apagados na origem:

```
DELETE FROM dbDestino..cd_cliente
WHERE cd_client NOT IN (
   SELECT cd_cliente from dbOrigem..cd_cliente)
```

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo, mas como eu disse sou leigo em comandos sql, acredito que tenha outra forma mais simples do que éssa, o que a de errado no meu comando?

Comment: @EduardoF.Santos Você pretende fazer isso uma vez só? Ou será um processo contínuo?

Comment: Toda vez que o Método for chamado!

Comment: Eu acredito que você deve dar uma estudada nesta cláusula merge então. Se você tentar entender parte por parte, vai ver que não é assim tão difícil. Você pode usar uma dúzia de outros comandos em separado, mas acho que vale mais a pena entender bem como este funciona.

Comment: Entendo, vou explorar ela, parece ter propriedade de muito utilidade, porem por hora, estou necessitando de algo simples, pegar o valor de uma tabela e atualizar a outra.

Comment: @EduardoF.Santos vou te passar uns comandos mais simples atualizando a resposta então.

Comment: OK, Obrigado, Ta ajudando muito

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19119/discussion-between-eduardo-f-santos-and-rodrigogq).

Comment: Certo, no meu caso é o UPDATE, esses (..) que voce colocou, significa as condições? cd_cliente, ds_endereco?

Comment: Não, é o esquema... as tabelas são referenciadas por [ServidorOuInstancia].[Esquema].[NomaTabela]... Geralmente o esquema padrão é o `dbo`, então você nem lembra que ele existe. Mas quando você quer acessar outro banco precisa passar esse nome. Se você já está logado no esquema `dbo` (mesmo local onde está a tabela destino), você não precisa escrever o nome, mas precisa indicar que passou pelo esquema... portanto `dbDestino.{dbo subentendido}.tb_cliente`

Comment: Achei que esse comando seria bem mais simples, vou ver aqui se faço esse SELECT fora do UPTATE, que retorna esse valor como string, muito complexo esses comandos, achei que a logica fosse mais simples, assim como eu estava tentando fazer, de qualquer forma vlw!

Answer (score 1):

Se o outro banco de dados estiver na mesma instância do servidor SQL:

```
    SELECT ds_endereco
    FROM [OutroBD].[schema].tb_enderecos
    WHERE cd_endereco = ...
```

Se estiver em outra instância ou outro servidor - que necessariamente deverá estar vinculado a este, você vai precisar usar `..` após a identificação do servidor:

```
    SELECT ds_endereco
    FROM [OutroBD]..[schema].tb_enderecos
    WHERE cd_endereco = ...
```

Comment: Ainda não tenho muita experiencia com os comando sql, desculpa, mas devo substituir somente o select ou esse código completo? o nome da outro tabela é tb_cliente!

Answer (score 0):

Não obtive a resposta que eu queria, consegui resolver o problema de outra forma, fazendo o SELECT fora do UPDATE, resolvi o PROBLEMA, mais não a DUVIDA!